# Control-space on Cinnamon

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-mapping, cinnamon

I installed [synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) on my Cinnamon desktop, and everything worked with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Then, at some point, it stopped working properly, and I had to hold down Control and hit space twice. Now it isn't working at all. Control-space seems to make the current window go out of focus, but I can't find it in the cinnamon control center.

I would like to know how to disable it for use with synapse or kupfer, as I don't need this cinnamon Control-space anyway. I run cinnamon 2.0.10, in case it helps.

Comment: Try looking for it in `gnome-control-center` instead. While cinnamon 2 is supposed to be free of Gnome there might be some residual settings still affected. I don't have version 2 installed yet so I can't check but have you looked through all the keyboard shortcuts in the "Windows" and "Universal Access" sections?

Comment: @terdon Good idea, but there wasn't anything. :( Maybe the window manager has some separate settings somewhere?? PS: thanks for the edit

Comment: As far as I know, cinnamon does not have a separate window manager. Personally, I use Win+Space to get at `gnome-do` (which is equivalent to synapse) if that works for you, see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/433724/how-do-i-disable-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-menu-in-linux-mint-13) for a tip on how to make it work without needing to hit space twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is that ibus is trapping control-space.  From http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=169930#p873888, here are directions to disable trapping of that key sequence in linux mint 17 (Qiana):

> Right-click the keyboard icon in the upper right corner of you Cinamon UI, and click preference. This should open the ibus preference. Here you shoud see the "Next input method" shortcut coming first and set to Ctrl-Space. Click on the '...' button next to the field, and in the popup click 'delete' and validate (or set another shortcut if you need it).